# Docker stop responding under load

Tags: nginx, docker

notice that docker stop responding under load. Here is the steps to reproduce the issue:

> *docker-machine create -d virtualbox web*
>
> *docker-machine ip web*

```
192.168.99.253
```

> *eval $(docker-machine env web)*
>
> *docker run --name app -d -p 3000:3000 ragesh/hello-express*
>
> *ab -n 100000 -c 100 http://192.168.99.253:3000/*

```
Server Hostname:        192.168.99.253
Server Port:            3000

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        207 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   145.726 seconds
Complete requests:      100000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      38900000 bytes
HTML transferred:       20700000 bytes
Requests per second:    686.22 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       145.726 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1.457 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          260.68 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.2      0      15
Processing:    32  145  14.1    140     237
Waiting:       32  145  14.1    140     237
Total:         36  146  14.1    140     237

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    140
  66%    146
  75%    151
  80%    155
  90%    165
  95%    173
  98%    185
  99%    196
 100%    237 (longest request)
```

Everything looks good even -n 100000.

> docker-machine create -d virtualbox router
>
> eval $(docker-machine env router)
>
> vi nginx.conf

```
upstream web {
    server 192.168.99.253:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web;
    }
}
```

> docker run --name router -p 80:80 -v $(pwd)/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro -d nginx
>
> docker-machine ip router

```
192.168.99.252
```

> ab -n 10000 -c 100 http://192.168.99.252:80/

```
Server Software:        nginx/1.9.14
Server Hostname:        192.168.99.252
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        207 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   32.631 seconds
Complete requests:      5957
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      2448327 bytes
HTML transferred:       1233099 bytes
Requests per second:    182.56 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       547.773 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       5.478 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          73.27 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    2  52.6      0    3048
Processing:     2  168  56.2    164    3002
Waiting:        2  168  56.2    163    3002
Total:          2  169  97.7    164    5032

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    164
  66%    171
  75%    176
  80%    178
  90%    185
  95%    192
  98%    199
  99%    209
 100%   5032 (longest request)
```

Expect the Requests per second will drop, but not except it drop so dramatically. And run ab several times, got connection error very often.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I suspect VirtualBox networking is not very performant here (but don't have real figures about it)

Comment: Agree, maybe it's the root cuase. Tried vmware, same result. Will try aws later to see if has the same issue.

Comment: I also tried deploy nginx and app in the same docker machine, still the same issue.